# Program to create a hash table

Tags: c++

I want to read an array of integers, hash each integer and put it into an hash table and later lookup the table to search for the value. What would be the efficient way to do that in c/c++? Thanks in advance

Comment: The efficent way to do it depends on how you want to treat collisions and whether collisons will occur.

Comment: What I was thinking was, one way of finding a match would be with collisions. For example, If a collision occur, then there is a match otherwise not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your compiler supports it, you can use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).  If your compiler doesn't support that yet, most implementations support `hash_set` (which is [well documented in the SGI STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html)).

Comment: I see that the unordered set is more efficient than others but I'm very confused on how to use it. This might be too much to ask but could you please give me a small example. Thanks.